# Usar variável PHP em ficheiro JS

Tags: php, javascript

Quero colocar código PHP em ficheiro JavaScript, não é ficheiro HTML. Como por exemplo aqui:

```
    document.getElementById('lbljour').innerHTML = "Jour " + date_today;
```

Com o código PHP ficaria algo deste gênero?

```
document.getElementById('lbljour').innerHTML = <?php echo trad($f_lng,"Jour "); ?> + date_today;
```

Comment: Exato, essa maneira funciona. Não funcionou?

Comment: se a extensão do ficheiro é .js, não dá. mas dentro de um ficheiro .php com o javascript lá dentro já dá

Comment: Nao funciona. Sim é um ficheiro .js

Comment: Você pode criar uma variável global com o conteúdo do PHP no ficheiro que chama o `.js`. No `.js` você usa a variável global.

Comment: Já fizeram uma resposta em baixo com aquilo que te disse.. O ficheiro .js tem muito código ou apenas aquela linha?

Comment: Desculpe o comentário... Mas o que está a fazer no mínimo resulta em uma grande falha de segurança e uma forma pouco ortodoxa de atingir o pretendido. Javascript é uma linguagem que é executado no cliente e o php um linguagem para o servidor...se este tipo de utilização for possível em javascript...  então muitos serviços seriam facilmente quebrados. O contrário sim é possível...ou seja pelo Php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu uso a seguinte técnica, no ficheiro PHP crio um objeto global:

```
<?php ?>
<script>
var lang = {
        day: 'Jour'
    };
</script>
<?php ?>
```

E uso no JS:

```
document.getElementById('lbljour').innerHTML = lang.day + date_today;
```

E na verdade, o `lang` no PHP vai ser criado conforme a linguagem atual, ou pode conter todas as variantes linguísticas no objeto.

Comment: Eu também uso dessa forma, uso as duas dependendo do que me dá mais jeito.

Comment: Exato, depende do volume de JS/PHP que tem criar.

Comment: Estou a seguir o seu exemplo, e quero passar esta variavel php para o js. Utilizei isso no meu ficheiro php "<?php ?><script>var lang = $lng;</script><?php ?>" e no ficheiro js, quero mostrar "alert(lang);"

Comment: Acho que tem que fazer um `echo` nesse caso: `var lang = "<?php echo $lng; ?>";`, atenção para as aspas no JS se quiser definir uma string.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível colocar código PHP num ficheiro `.js` porque o PHP não interpreta ficheiros com essa terminação.

Podes criar um script no ficheiro PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('lbljour').innerHTML = <?php echo trad($f_lng,"Jour "); ?> + date_today;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se está a tentar escrever código PHP dentro de um ficheiro `.JS` não é possível. Uma vez que o servidor não vai ler o `PHP` lá dentro. Se tem apenas esse código nesse ficheiro, aconselho a meter o código dentro do ficheiro `.php`.

Dentro do ficheiro `php` podes meter o seguinte:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('lbljour').innerHTML = <?php echo trad($f_lng,"Jour "); ?> + date_today;
</script>
```